# RIDC Update against Oracle WCC 10G Server fails with Creation Date Invalid Error message

Tags: java, oracle-ucm

I have an application that performs an Update to a Content Item via RIDC.  The Item is specified via *Content ID*. Since the **UPDATE_DOCINFO** service needs *dID* the **DOC_INFO** service is run first to get it.

**DOC_INFO** returns Information just fine. However, when **UPDATE_DOCINFO** is run, It always seems to return an error message indicating that *Creation Date is invalid*. The content Item updates without that error message via the Native Web UI.  My code works when pointed at an Oracle WCC 11G server.

I've tried:

1. Adding *dID* to a new DataBinder, without **dCreateDate**
2. Adding *dID* to a new DataBinder, with **dCreateDate**

   - adding *dCreateDate* as a date Object (from **DOC_INFO** response I've tried)

     - via `getDate()`
     - manual conversion with `DataObjectEncodingUtils.decodeDate()` (w/ `get()`)
   - adding as a string

     - converting with SimpleDateFormatter similar to How RIDC encodes (w/ `getDate()`)
     - manual conversion with `DataObjectEncodingUtils.encodeDate()` (w/ `getDate()`)
     - as ""
     - as **null**
     - `get()` instead of `getDate()`
3. Directly using **DOC_INFO**'s response Binder
4. Using the 11G RIDC Library (3 above) 
   5 Using the 10G RIDC Library (1-3 above)

All the approaches listed have returned the same error message.

Comment: What format are you receiving for dCreateDate from DOC_INFO?

Comment: I've using `java.util.date` for the date variable, and setting it with `databinder.getLocalData().setDate("dCreateDate", someDateVar);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Working With Oracle Support on the issue I found an answer.

**RIDC** defaults to an **ISO8601** formatted Date. However, my server is using a different date format.

The solution was:

1. Set a the **UserDateFormat** property on the *RIDC Binder*.
2. Serialize all dates into the *RIDC Binder* with a matching format.

   - Luckily 
     [UserDateFormat](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?parent=SrDetailText&sourceId=3-11500161841&id=445341.1) uses a very similar format string to 
     [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

dCreateDate shouldn't be required to do the UPDATE_DOCINFO.  There must be something up-stream (inside Content Server such as a profile/rule or component) causing that field to be required and/or setting it to a value.  It's also possible that something is causing this field to get set even when you aren't setting it (either way I'd dump the binder when you aren't setting it just to be sure it somehow isn't getting set).

I found this article you may or may not have seen: http://onwardpath.com/2015/09/19/date-formatting-while-using-ridc.html which includes some additional information for setting the date format.

What might help is posting what the stack trace looks like (if any) in the Content Server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using using [oracle.stellent.ridc.model.impl.DataObjectEncodingUtils.decodeDate](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10316_01/ContentIntegration/ridc/Javadoc/oracle/stellent/ridc/model/impl/DataObjectEncodingUtils.html#decodeDate(java.lang.String)) to transform the String (in format 2010-02-04 06:00:00Z) to a Java Calendar object.

More info can be found [here](http://www.redstonecontentsolutions.com/technical-blog/parse-date-usingridc).